# CakePHP alphanumeric validation failing

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I am trying to figure out why my validation is failing. If I remove "required" it inserts but the description is blank in the database row.

var_dump($this->request);
outputs:

```
array(1) { ["AddrTypeRef"]=> array(2) { ["description"]=> string(9) "safasfasf" ["active_flag"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

model:

```
public $validate = array(
            'description' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric', 
                'message' => 'Only letters and numbers allowed in description',
                'required' => true
            ),
            'active_flag' => array( 
                'rule' => array('boolean'),
                'message' => 'Incorrect value for myCheckbox',
                'required' => true              
            )

    );
```

Comment: Is your model called "AddrTypeRef" ?

Comment: Well, Addrtyperef so i dont know why it is AddrTypeRef

Answer (score 0):

The form has to use the same model name for $this->save() to work properly.

So, your $form->create('modelname') must include the correct model name.

In your case, if your model is `Addrtyperef`, make sure in the view to use `$form->create('Addrtyperef')`